# How to calculate a bounding rectangle of a polygon?

Tags: java, 2d, physics

```
Polygon poly = new Polygon();
poly.getPoints().setAll(5d, 15d, 15d, 25d, 5d, 30d);
```

How do I calculate the Polygon's height and width? There is no poly.getWidth() or poly.getHeight() method in javafx.

Answer (score 4):

As lealand raised "width" and "height" are somewhat vague terms.

Here is a straightforward approach to finding the width and height of the [AABB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-aligned_bounding_box#Axis-aligned_minimum_bounding_box):

```
double minX = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double maxX = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
double minY = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double maxY = -Double.MAX_VALUE;

double[] points = poly.getPoints().toArray();

for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
    double x = points[i];
    double y = points[i + 1];
    minX = Math.min(minX, x);
    maxX = Math.max(maxX, x);
    minY = Math.min(minY, y);
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, y);    
}

double width = maxX - minX;
double height = maxY - minY;
```

Answer (score 0):

A polygon doesn't have a height in width, as it's simply a collection of vertices. In fact, these properties only really make sense as we commonly use them when you have four (as in a rectangle).

You'll have to define and write your own methods for calculating these properties. For example, the width might be defined as the maximum distance between any two vertices, and the height might be the length between the mid-point of that line and the third vertex.